# Python 2: Best way to terminate WXWidgets app main thread when user closes app?

Tags: python, multithreading

The situation is this:

I'm writing a simple game using WXWidgets. The logic I have is that the game's main routine first launches the GUI, and then spawns a new separate thread to actually run the game's logic. The game logic runs sequentially, occasionally (but not very frequently) accepting input from the user via the GUI and updating the GUI with game data. The game uses a lot of audio so the GUI itself is not being manipulated much.

The game thread often does things that must block - and this is appropriate given that this is a game. AI computations, loading data from the Internet, etc. all cause the game thread to block. This is fine since the game thread manages the UI to make sure users can't manipulate the UI in any situation where the game thread might not be able to respond.

The problem arises if the user hits Alt+F4 or Command-Q to exit the app completely. This causes the main GUI to close, but it obviously does not kill the game logic thread. The game thread continues running in the background, now disconnected from the UI, and as soon as it tries to interact with the UI it will crash (as would be expected in that situation).

What I am looking to do is to have a way to signal to the thread that the user has exited the app - BUT - without having to litter my code with tons of "check if the user closed the GUI" routines. First of all, that method wouldn't even always work since, as I said, often the game thread blocks while it is doing something and thus several seconds could go by where such a call never gets checked.

Since the game thread starts out as a function, I was thinking a good way to possibly solve this would be if there is some way for me to cause a custom exception to be raised on the thread. I could then write a simple wrapper function would wrap the main game function inside a try block, specifically looking for that exception. If that exception is raised, I could then gracefully close sockets, shut down AI players, etc. as necessary, then gracefully exit the thread.

Is there a way to cause something like this to happen?

Here is some very rough pseudocode to illustrate the problem:

Currently:

```
def PlayGame(self):
    # Get the game ready
    self.initGame()

    # Go into a loop to run the game
    while (True):
        # Get user's move
        move = self.GUI_GetMove()
        # Act based on the move
        gameOver = self.processMove(move)
        # If we got True, game is over.
        if (gameOver == True): return
        # Run the AI's logic - THIS MIGHT BLOCK AS THE AI PROCESSES AND/OR 
        # GRABS STUFF OFF THE INTERNET ETC.
        move = self.AI_GetMove()
        # Act based on the move
        gameOver = self.processMove(move)
        # (Let's pretend in this game the AI never ends the game)
        continue
```

Very ugly method:

```
def PlayGame(self):
    # Get the game ready
    self.initGame()

    # Go into a loop to run the game
    while (True):
        # Get user's move
        move = self.GUI_GetMove()
        if (move == "EXIT" or self.GUI_Exited == True):
            return
        # Act based on the move
        gameOver = self.processMove(move)
        # If we got True, game is over.
        if (gameOver == True): return
        if (self.GUI_Exited == True):
            return
        # Run the AI's logic - THIS MIGHT BLOCK AS THE AI PROCESSES AND/OR 
        # GRABS STUFF OFF THE INTERNET ETC.
        move = self.AI_GetMove()
        # self.AI_GetMove might take 10 or more seconds - game will appear to
        # be STUCK if user exits during an AI Process!
        if (self.GUI_Exited == True):
            return
        # Act based on the move
        gameOver = self.processMove(move)
        if (self.GUI_Exited == True):
            return
        # (Let's pretend in this game the AI never ends the game)
        continue

        # That self.GUI_Exited code is duplicated SO many times - making
        # this an awfully ugly and confusing block of code! In the real
        # app, the check might need to be duplicated 100+ times!!!
```

What I'd like to be able to do:

```
def PlayGame(self):
    try:
        self._PlayGame()
    except UserExitedApplicationError:
        self.AI.Stop() 
        self.sockets.closeAll() 
        return # return gracefully so thread exits
```

(Remember a lot of that is not real code or functions - this just gives you the idea of what I was thinking would be a good solution)

Answer (score 0):

Please look into daemon threads as part of Python's `threading` library. Threads are non-daemon by default, and Python will let you exit if only daemon threads are running. If you specify your background game logic thread as a daemon thread when you first create it, the thread will automatically be killed when your main non-daemon thread exits.

Note that this is only the easiest and most straightforward way to do this and it has its downsides. The thread will be killed before it can release any resources. You can also use thread signaling to make that thread release its resources first before stopping. The simplest form of thread signaling is Events, also part of the `threading` library.